# CodingBat help on counting elements in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am solving this problem on [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p109783) and it shows that my code work for all cases but not for other cases.

> Given an array of ints, return true if the value 3 appears in the array exactly 3 times, and no 3's > are next to each other.
>
> haveThree({3, 1, 3, 1, 3}) → true
>
> haveThree({3, 1, 3, 3}) → false
>
> haveThree({3, 4, 3, 3, 4}) → false

My code:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[i + 1] == 3)
            return false;
        if (nums[i] == 3)
            count++;
    }
    if (nums[nums.length-1] == 3)
        count++;
    return(count==3);
}
```

These are the test results:

```
Expected Run        
have Three({3, 1, 3, 1, 3}) → true  true OK     
have Three({3, 1, 3, 3}) → false    false   OK      
have Three({3, 4, 3, 3, 4}) → false false   OK      
have Three({1,  3, 1, 3, 1, 2}) → false false   OK      
have Three({1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3}) → true   true    OK      
have Three({1, 3, 3, 1, 3}) → false false   OK      
have Three({1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3}) → false    false   OK      
have Three({3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4}) → true    true    OK       
have Three({3, 3, 3}) → false   false   OK      
have Three({1, 3}) → false  false   OK      
have Three({3}) → false false   OK      
have Three({1}) → false false   OK      
other tests X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make it way too complicated, simply count the number of occurrences of `3` and perform a check:

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i]==3)
        count++;
}
return (count == 3);
```

Optionally, you can make things a bit faster, since if your at position *n-1* and you have thus far counted only no or only one `3`, you know this might fail, thus:

```
for(int i=0; count <= 3 && (count == 3 || i < nums.length-2+count); i++){
    if(nums[i]==3)
        count++;
}
return count == 3;
```

This also stops from the moment more than three `3`s are encountered. But I advice not to, use this since it makes the code more unreadable.

**EDIT** (since two consecutive `3`'s should fail):

In case no two consecutive `3`s should be present, you can modify this using two `for` loops:

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i < nums.length-1; i++){
    if(nums[i] == 3 && nums[i+1] == 3) {
        return false;
    }
}
for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i]==3)
        count++;
}
return (count == 3);
```

Again you can speed up some aspects by *merging* two `for`s, but given the level of your question - no insult intended - you better follow the separation of responsibilities paradigm: let the different part of the code do different things.

If you really want to merge it into a single `for`, you could do it by:

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i] == 3) {
        count++;
        if(i+1 < nums.length && nums[i+1] == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return (count == 3);
```

Finally to make things complete, you should also include a `null` check, a final version thus reads:

```
public boolean haveThree (int[] nums) {
    if(nums == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i < nums.length && count <= 3; i++){
        if(nums[i] == 3) {
            count++;
            if(i+1 < nums.length && nums[i+1] == 3) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count == 3);
}
```

**What is probably wrong with your code**

It is possible someone enters an array with `.length == 0`, in that case, this fragment:

```
if (nums[nums.length-1] == 3)
    count++;
```

Will result in a query on `if(nums[-1] == 3)` now `-1` doesn't exist as an index, thus [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). I tested this on *CodeBat*, and indeed, that seems to be the problem.

A way to solve the problem is thus adding a *"zero length" check*:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
    if(nums.length <= 0) //hint, although a length is never negative, one better uses "strong conditions"
        return false;
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[i + 1] == 3)
            return false;
        if (nums[i] == 3)
            count++;
    }
    if (nums[nums.length-1] == 3)
        count++;
    return(count==3);
}
```

But I would advice to use a version stated above because these are - in general - methodologies to make less mistakes.

My compliments to *CodeBat* for making programmers aware of *defensive* and *total programming*.

Comment: `Given an array of ints, return true if the value 3 appears in the array exactly 3 times, and no 3's are next to each other.` OP omitted a very important information ... I'll edit the question to note that.

Comment: Well, you don't need two loop. You can do both checks in one loop, but you have to change the first check to `i < nums.length - 1 && nums[i] == 3 && nums[i + 1] == 3` ... maybe two loops are more readable :D.

Comment: @Tom: I've updated it, but I strongly advice against it (at least for now), since it makes things more unreadable (and things are already quite hard for beginning programmers)...

Comment: Yes and I like your change of my suggestion :).

Comment: @Tom in my first try i did the exact thing u did(posted my code in the question )it works on all runs but it did not work on other runs it still consider it as a wrong solution)

Comment: @sarachatila: see last section, found the bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (nums[i] == 3) {
            if (nums.length > 1) {

                if (i == nums.length - 1 && nums[i - 1] != 3) {

                    count++;
                } else if (i < nums.length - 1 && nums[i + 1] != 3) {

                    count++;
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return count == 3;

}
```